How to restart the terminal in VS Code
I want to reset the terminal(any used) in Visual Studio Code with a hotkey. I don't see any option in the docs.

why do you want to reset a terminal? are you sure you don't want to just restart your shell?

@starball what is the difference? Do you know a hotkey to always "restart the shell" ? that works in every occasion?

There is no single hotkey or command to reset the terminal.
However, a possible solution is to combine different commands "to close the current terminal, open a new one, and focus it".
To achieve this with a single hotkey:
1- Install the Multi Command extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command
2- Open settings.json by: open the command palette Ctrl+Shift+P and type Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON). This will allow you to configure the Multi Command extension.
Add the following configuration to your settings.json file:
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.newTerminalAndKillPrevious",
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.terminal.kill",
            "workbench.action.terminal.new",
            "workbench.action.terminal.focus"
        ]
    }
]

3- Open your keybindings.json by going to the command palette Ctrl+Shift+P and typing Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON).
Add the following configuration to map the command to Ctrl+Shift+End (or any key combination you prefer):
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+end",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        "command": "multiCommand.newTerminalAndKillPrevious"
    }
}

4- Close the setting and press they hotkey you just set to reset the terminal ctrl+shift+end
Note: If ctrl+shift+end is not working for you especially on Mac, try setting a different hotkey combination

or you can kill the terminal by pressing trash icon at the right top of terminal and make a new one by pressing + icon
